# $(window).scroll not accurate, when scrolling fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate element's position, so between certain page scroll position, his css is changed.
Take a look at this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/6RtTX/8/

The problem is - `$(window).scroll` is not so accurate, so if i scroll very fast, it becomes really messy.

Is there any way around for this problem? Can I queue those operations in $(window).scroll method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debounce it - scroll events fire quite often.

Comment: tried that - didn't help, debounce just skips the method calls inbetween intervals

Comment: For this simple thing, you just should set `position:fixed` when the scrolled view is in the right zone

Comment: it's just a small example. I want to be able to do more advanced repositioning

Comment: I don't see this "messy" behavior you speak of. It works perfectly fine in Firefox with its smooth scroll, and Chrome has a very little flickering which is default to it and the flickering won't go away unless you use `position:fixed`.

Comment: ok, as i said - it's just a small example, don't want to use position:fixed; take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/6RtTX/18/ and try to scroll the page really fast (using scrollbar) and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

try altering your fiddle's code like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if ( event.pageY > 100 && event.pageY < 5000) {
        $('.test').css({
            'left' : $(window).scrollTop() - 80,
            'top' : $(window).scrollTop() + 100
        });            
    }
});
```

By using the passed event to get the measurements instead of measuring again, i find that the accuracy improves considerably.

Comment: It does not work for me, what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Im using 1.8.3, but this should really work with any version of jQuery.

Comment: Not sure because yesterday I noticed that recent jQ versions do not have that `event.pageY`